# Flutter Home Screen Widgets

Tags: android, flutter, dart, home-screen-widget

I am looking for a way to create Flutter home screen widgets.
For Android is enough for me.

I know that there are at least 2 documentations (1 package):

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/flutter-home-screen-widgets#0

In itself a nice guide, but in my Android Studio the possibility to create a widget file is hidden by default. I can activate it in the menu configuration, but when I click on new app widget nothing happens.

Then there is this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget

Unfortunately I can't get any further with the information, for me this is the first time that I have come into indirect contact with Android, I have no idea which file I should now copy which code.

If someone would like to help me or knows another possibility, I would be very happy.

Comment: There is currently no way to create home screen widgets with flutter. The package you reference is used to pass data to the widgets. To create widgets that would be done in the android and/or ios folder of your flutter project. Since they have to done in the platforms native language. So from that point you would follow documentation as if you weren't doing flutter. Since flutter itself does not "care" whether a widget exists or not.